# C++ priority queue behaves wierdly when using reference for the head element

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I have below code trying to dump the values stored in a priority_queue in C++:

```
priority_queue<Point, vector<Point>, myCmp> pq;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Point p(i,i);
    pq.push(p);
}
const Point& p0 = pq.top();
while(!pq.empty()) {
    cout<<p0.x<<p0.y<<endl;
    pq.pop();
}//I'm getting output like "00 11 22 33 ... 99"
```

As the comment in the code said, my reference variable p0 is keep changing every time the queue pops a value. That does not make sense to me, because I think p0 should always be a reference to (0,0) object, i.e. the front of the queue at the beginning. I know I can use

```
Point p0 = pq.top()
```

to get a copy of the front element and avoid the issue. But still, can someone explain the problem of using references?

P.S. I did the same for C++ queue and didn't observe this issue.

Comment: It is a standard practice w/ enumerable; that when iterating them, modifying them does not guarantee reference will continue to be valid.

Comment: p0 points to the object that is stored in the front of the queue. There is no guarentee that that stays the same location after the pop (indeed, if you used a list<Point> as the underlying container or it decides to reallocate the vector<Point>, you'll be pointing at nothing after the pop!). This is "working" for you only because the vector is not resizing.

Answer (score 1):

After you change `priority_queue` (for example by popping) all references are invlidated. So it's **undefined**(?) behaviour

### What happens:

You get reference to the top element. It's stored as first element of underlying `std::vector`, so you have just link to first element in the `vector`. When `popping` you rearrange `vector` to new state with deleted previous top element. New top element should be first in `vector`. So, if `vector` is in same place reference points to new top

**Added:**

Some references:

make_pop:
§ 23.6.4.3/4

> void pop();
> 4 Eﬀects:
> pop_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
> c.pop_back();

§ 25.4.6.2/2

> Eﬀects: Swaps the value in the location first with the value in the location last - 1 and makes
> [first,last - 1) into a heap.

I didn't find info that `pop_back` for `vector` is exactly the same as `erase(end() - 1)` (only for strings), but it's seems to be true.

§ 23.3.6.5/3

> iterator erase(const_iterator position);
> iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
> Eﬀects: Invalidates iterators and references **at or after the point of the erase**

So it's seems it's valid to rely that reference will point to new top after `pop` because even reallocation seems to be impossible. But it's not good idea to use it anyway.

---

*All reference to N3242

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'm going to give a more in depth answer with my comment.

So when you get a reference, you are actually just getting a pointer to the front element. The std::vector is the underlying container, so the code you have is (in functionality) more similar to this than what you have:

```
vector<Point> pq;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Point p(i,i);
    pq.push_back(p);
}
Point* p = &pq[0];

while(!pq.empty()) 
{
    cout<<p->x<<p->y<<endl;
    pq.erase(pq.begin(),pq.begin()+1);
}//I'm getting output like "00 11 22 33 ... 99"
```

Now there is NO guarentee that p* points to the first member of the vector after you start messing with the values. Indeed, if I add a pq.resize(100); after the p assignment, while pq[0] still equals (0,0), p points to outer random un-reserved memory (reading either outputs junk or you get a seg-fault). You are getting the right values out right now due to pure chance! That is why you always need to copy or move before the pop.